# PHP validation showing wrong icon

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am new to PHP. I am here trying to show error icon when validation fails

PHP

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = "";
$name = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  } 
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<div class="<?php if (empty($nameErr)){ echo 'success-validate';} else { echo 'failure-validate'; } ?>">                
</div>
```

Here, I am always getting the success-validate icon when the page loads for first time. But when I click the submit button, the validation is working fine. Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: can you here use `<input type=submit>` ???

Comment: @kumar, Before clicking the submit itself (I meant when the page is loading for the first time), the validation icon is displaying. When I click on the submit button, the validation is working fine.

Comment: try with `if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")) {`

Comment: @kumar, no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem here is that you have 3 states (**valid**, **no-valid** and **no-validation-used**) instead of two as you think of at first.

So, the simplest solution can be to add another flag which tells that validation has started, eg:

```
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = "";
$name = "";
$validationApplied = false;  // here
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $validationApplied = true;
  
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  } 
}
```

In your html you then can check both variables like this:

```
<div class="<?php if ($validationApplied) { echo empty($nameErr) ? 'success-validate' : 'failure-validate'; } ?>">                
</div>
```

Another solution can be to check both `$nameErr` and `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"`. It's the same as above approach, just instead of distinct flag you check `REQUEST_METHOD`:

```
<div class="<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { echo empty($nameErr) ? 'success-validate' : 'failure-validate'; } ?>">                
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried validationApplied flag approach and it worked!!